# ngAnimate not work on ngIf with slide animation

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I have this html:

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" />
  <div ng-if="checked" class="animate">
  Show when checked:
  <span>
    This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.
  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

and this css:

```
.animate-enter, 
.animate-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
} 

.animate-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active{
    left: -100%;
}
```

but the animation not working, here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DmTPvBMdh25Bzp8H2yHk?p=preview

can some one tell me why it is not working? (I tried to do it also with `ng-animate='animate'` - didn't work)

I just want to create some sliding effect when tabs are changing, this is simplification of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change your `css` so that it meets the standards of `ngAnimate`, like this:

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    position: absolute;
} 

.animate.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.animate.ng-enter.animate.ng-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.animate.ng-leave.animate.ng-leave-active{
    left: -100%;
}
```

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzmWgHSOTiCHr6LXyRh6?p=preview)